# How to center text next to a responsive image in Bootstrap3

Tags: css, text, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm using the Boostrap's navbar, inside which there is an image brand (responsive) and some text (menu items). I would like to center the text within the div, but I don't know how: if I center the text in the CSS, there is more space between the left corner of the monitor and the "Home" and and less space between the last "Link" in the right and the right corner in the monitor. It's as if my code takes the div size, subtracts the image size and center the text in the remaining space.

I thought about putting a negative left margin, but because the image is responsive I don't know what value to give.

Can you help me? 
http://jsfiddle.net/a001dxn6/2/

**HTML**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="official_logo.png" /></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Specialità <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#"></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">La pizza napoletana</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Le specialità della casa</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Eventi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar .navbar-nav {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
vertical-align: top;
}

.navbar-default {
background-color: transparent;
border-color: darkorange;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand > img {
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[fixed] Just add CSS: `.navbar-brand { position: fixed; left: 1vw; }`

Comment: With this solution the button in the navbar collapse is moved to the left, nearby the logo. I'm trying to fix it, in order to have the button in the right corner (as default). Any suggestion?

Comment: sorry, just saw your question now. Once again I'm not seeing in the jsfiddle what you just described. Everything looks O.K. here. Nothing visually changes for me with or without the extra CSS line.

Comment: Adding position: fixed in the CSS I solved the problem, but when I resize the screen the button of the navbar-collapse is placed in the left (as you can see in this image: [link](http://i64.tinypic.com/zltd90.jpg) ). Without the position: fixed rule, instead, the button is in the right corner. I'm trying to use your solution but keeping the button in the right (on the red X)

Comment: fixed it! Read main answer: 
(1) I switched from navbar-header to navbar-brand. (2) now the problem of appearing in the center jumped from the menu icon to the Brand icon. (3) I fixed it with: left: 10px; however it kept varying from 10px to 20px margin as screen was resized. (4) so I used vw (viewport width) and margin is constant.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it's totally fixed

Answer (score 0):

can't really test with the fiddle, since there's no image.

have you tried removing `text-aling: center` from `.navbar` classes 
and adding:

```css
.dropdown, .dropdown-menu{
    text-align: center;
}
```

? let me know if it works.

Comment: Hi warkentien, first of all thank you for the answer. I tried your solution but it doesn't work: the text is aligned to the left doing that. If you want you can edit the code in the fiddle adding an image url (I have place an image, but problably fiddle clears it automatically)

Comment: I'm confused as to what you really want. 
If all you want is one line with a specific effect: add an id.
If it's more general: you can set margin in vw (viewport width, parts of 0-100) and vh (viewport height 0-100) ex: `margin-left: 30vw` it's a responsive solution. 

Try to explain better what you're struggling with (add more stuff to the fiddle and send a new link here.)

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry for my bad English, I'll try to explain better. I want a navbar with the logo in the left corner and text in the center. However, with my code, the text isn't centered at all: there is more space between the left corner of the monitor and the "Home" and less space between the last "Link" in the right and the right corner of the monitor. It's as if the code takes the total size of the div, subtracts the image size and centers the text in the remaining space, but I would like the text centered in the total size of the div

Comment: Aha! Now I understand exactly what's your problem.
However, I'm running a Chrome Browser and it perfectly centered, 
I even went on Photoshop to prove it (image): [link](http://postimg.org/image/yd70v19g5/)
What browser are you using?

Comment: The collapse is centered, yes, but if you enlarge the screen, in order to see the normal navbar, the text isn't centered at all. I explained very badly my problem, I'm going to edit the question

Comment: I can finally understand and see the problem. 
I'm working on a solution here.